# Get the value of nested formgroups in angular

Tags: angular

i have hierarchy of controls looks like:
formArray ->formGroup-> formArray -> formGroup ->formControl

But i don't know how to get the value of nested controls and this hierarchy can goes upto any level. Please help.

Comment: why do you need this. Can you provide some context to your question as well as a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:
`this.form.get('parent.child.gradChild.grandGrandChild').value`

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Chaka for answer, but i cannot hard code parent.child.gradChild.grandGrandChild